# Image rotation script not working on AJAX load of new image

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, rotation

I have a wordpress website: http://rundog.art/ that uses a random image rotation script (between -5deg and 5deg) to rotate images that appear when you hover over article titles on the home page.

I've used AJAX to navigate through the pages of article titles (using left and right arrows), but when you load the next page the script is not triggered and the new images aren't rotated.

I've tried playing around with an ajaxComplete function but am a massive rookie at javascript so it isn't working.

My original rotation code:

```
$(".pt-cv-ifield img").each( function() {
  var rNum = (Math.random()*10)-5;  
  $(this).css( {   
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+rNum+'5deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+rNum+'5deg)'  
  } );  
} );
```

My attempt at the AJAX version:

```
$( "document" ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $(".pt-cv-ifield img").each( function() {
  var rNum = (Math.random()*10)-5;  
  $(this).css( {   
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+rNum+'5deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+rNum+'5deg)'  
  } );  
} );  
} );
```

Any help would be much appreciated.